# Display corner stack text

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I am trying to make a complication that shows an inspirational message. I figured I start by making a corner complication and displaying a hardcoded message but I cannot figure out how to even display that. Here's what I have so far from reading different articles and apple documentation. I'm using the Corner Stack text template.

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the current timeline entry

     let date = Date()
    var template: CLKComplicationTemplate!

    template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText()

    var firstTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Don't Worry")
    var secondTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Be Happy")

    template.outerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Don't Worry")
    template.innerTextProvider = secondTextProvier

    let entry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: date, complicationTemplate: template)
    handler(entry)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `getLocalizableSampleTemplate` method:

```
func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
        switch complication.family {
        case .graphicCorner:
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText()
            template.innerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "innerT")
            template.outerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "outerT")
            handler(template)
        default:
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
```

You should also consider using a `switch case` in all your methods in the `ComplicationController` Class, but it is not necessary:

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        // Call the handler with the current timeline entry
        switch complication.family {
        case .graphicCorner:
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText()
            template.innerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "innerT")
            template.outerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "outerT")
            handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template))
        default:
            handler(nil)
        }
    }
```

Make sure you are using the correct Watchface, the GraphicCornerStack-Complication is only usable in the Corners of the "Round"-Infograph-Watchface.

You should also pay attention to the selected Complications of your project. If you open your General-Settings of your WatchKit Extension Target, you should see an area called "Complications Configuration" and you should select the correct complication in the list ("Graphic Corner" in your case). If you don't handle other possible complications with `switch case` statements you shouldn't select more than one possible complication here.